# What should Add Data to Profile URL point to? Where will it be shown to the users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, authentication

Two questions about the "Add Data to Profile URL" configuration option in the new enhanced auth dialog already exist, but sadly they do not have complete answers. Here are the questions for reference :

[Open Graph Beta: Add Data to Profile URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7605474/open-graph-beta-add-data-to-profile-url)
[How to configure 'Add Data to Profile URL' in Auth Dialog?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9597532/how-to-configure-add-data-to-profile-url-in-auth-dialog)

I have a website which allows users to login with FB credentials. I intend to use open graph `publish_actions` feature for some of the user actions on my website. I am configuring the new enhanced auth dialog and am unable to understand the configuration option `Add Data to Profile URL`.

My Questions :

1. What should this URL point to? -- Is it a page on my website? Is it a special App page that Facebook makes available? Will Facebook ever fetch this page and parse the contents to be displayed somewhere? The documentation on this is very vague -- It says "The new user flow URL for your app. This URL should point to a URL that expedites for engagement and action publishing. See the Add Data to Profile section below.". I do not understand what this `new user flow URL` is.. ! The `section below` doesn't say much more either
2. Where will this URL be shown to users - both user already using my app and their friends who are not yet using my app? Will this be displayed in the news_feed stories or the Timeline? If so will `authenticated referrals` kick in when the user clicks on this link?
3. The documentation says that if this configuration option is set then the app will get a `Perforated Unit` and `Add to My Timeline Link` -- Where will these two things appear -- in the aggregations shown on timelines of users of my app? Will I get these if I set the option to any value (like my website homepage) or should it point to a page with specific `<og:xxx>` tags?. The screen shots are isolated ones and I do not understand where they will appear on the user's profile/timeline.

I have been reading the documentation repeatedly but I do not understand this specific section. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.